# AWS API gateway Time out for same condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am using AWS lambda + API Gateway. API is created in .net core.

When i try to call same API it sometimes returns result within 2-3 seconds,while in some time it gives endpoint time error. I  am not changing any condition or parameter of API. Everything remains same. still the response time is random. I read in AWS document that there is limitation in API Gateway up to 29 seconds. but this is a awkward behavior i face of API gateway.

I also want to know the reason behind this. why it responds with random time frame.

Comment: What timeout do you have set for your lambda (this can often be defaulted to as little as 5 seconds), or can you confirm that you sometimes have to wait 30s before you get a timeout?

Comment: I have not set timeout for lambda or in API gateway. my concern is API gateway's response is random. for same record get call it takes different time. like it responds within 2-3 seconds while on some times it gives endpoint time out error after 29 seconds.

Comment: OK- this means that the lambda is not always taking a consistent amount of time (API Gateway timing out is a side-effect of this, but not the cause). To debug further you'll need to share you lambda code, or, instead, add enough logging to your lambda to determine the point where it stops.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have increased the lambda function's memory uto 2GB and also increased its timeout to 5 minute. and till now i am not facing the issue. 

Thanks for the suggestion.